# Check permissions not accurate for AD Group changes

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, 2019

I've removed a user from an AD group, though check permissions are still showing them as having permissions due to that group.

I'm aware of WindowsTokenLifetime, but that is set to 10 hours, while the check permissions are still wrong after 16 hours.

Is there a different token that expires on a different schedule? At what point will check permissions show accurate data after a change in windows group membership?

This is SharePoint 2019.

Comment: Has the user accessed the SharePoint farm since the membership change?

Comment: No. Not yet. I expect that would get a token refreshed, but I'd also like to ensure that IT can correctly say who has access.

Comment: Have a read of https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/sambetts/why-sharepoint-check-permissions-can-give-wrong-results-for-ad-groups

Comment: That article states 24 hours for non-interactive logins, and 1 hour token cache for interactive logins. Then what's the WindowsTokenLifetime that's 10 hours?

Comment: Different caches for different purposes I believe.  The WindowsTokenLifetime is for the security token service which is not used for the “Check Permissions” functionality.  Note that while “Check Permissions” may not show correct group membership, the Security Token Service will still correctly enforce the current group membership (assuming the user has logged off/on since the membership was updated).